# Model unable to identify distant objects

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have made a object recognition and detection model using tensorflow. It identifies the images which are clearly visible but its unable to identify if the same object is at a large distance. I am using Faster RCNN model.  the model is able to identify the same object when it is closer but not when it is at a far distance. It has been trained already for the same object. How can i make the model identify objects at a distance?

Answer (score 0):

You can resize and add padding using data augmentation to images with objects that are clearly visible so that they look like they are in a big distance and train your model further with those images